# Why does DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory not expose setExceptionListener method?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I am in the process of building out telemetry and monitoring for an application that uses a `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` to register `@JmsListener` annotated methods.

I already have an error handler registered for exceptions thrown while receiving a message, but I want to register a similar error handler to monitor the connection integrity between my app and the topic(s) to which it is subscribed.

I found this nifty `setExceptionListener` method in `AbstractMessageListenerContainter`, but the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` does not provide a configuration method to set this attribute.

I've searched through the spring framework JMS javadocs to see if there's any explanation as to *why* this configuration option doesn't exist. Does anyone know of a reason why this is not exposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what eventually provided me access to this attribute. I tested that I can still receive messages from the topic as before

```
public class PortalJmsListenerContainerFactory
        extends DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory {

    private ExceptionListener exceptionListener;

    /**
     * @see DefaultMessageListenerContainer#setExceptionListener
     */
    public void setExceptionListener(ExceptionListener exceptionListener) {
        this.exceptionListener = exceptionListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected DefaultMessageListenerContainer createContainerInstance() {
        return new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeContainer(DefaultMessageListenerContainer container) {
        super.initializeContainer(container);

        if (this.exceptionListener != null) {
            container.setExceptionListener(this.exceptionListener);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad to hear @sachin1!

Comment: thanks @andrewdleach this is very helpful, got stuck on same issue. for those who are interested this is being target on 2.x https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22402 .

Comment: Glad to see this is coming full circle! I completely forgot about that issue I put on their tracker

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an omission, or was considered not something that was felt necessary to expose. I suggest you open an [Improvement JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR).

In the meantime you can get a reference to the container from the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` (using the id), cast it and set the property.

**EDIT**

Something like this should work...

```
@Bean
public SmartInitializingSingleton lcPostProcessor(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
    return () -> registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(c ->
            ((DefaultMessageListenerContainer) c).setExceptionListener(myExceptionListener()));
}
```

It runs after all the beans are created but before any containers are started.

Comment: Thanks! This helps point me in the right direction. I've filed an Improvement issue in their backlog, but until such a time that becomes a release candidate, do you have a suggestion for how perform this post processing _after_ the Container(s) get created?

Comment: Your proposed solution did not work. Please see my answer for what did work

Comment: Sure, the containers were not yet available when i tried to grab a reference to them through `registry.getListenerContainers()`. Threw a NPE

Comment: Ah yes, my bad; the containers are registered by another `SmartInitializingSingleton` which runs after this one :( Well, at least I pointed you in the right direction - while I can understand you removed the "accept", it seems a bit severe to remove the upvote as well :)

Comment: good point. my bad. i've restored it because it did point me in the right direction. my apologies